# Thumbnails not showing correctly in a view in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, view, thumbnails, drupal-8

So I made a view that would display all my articles of a certain content type. I added a default thumbnail to be displayed if no custom image is uploaded. The problem is that in my views section everything looks like it should, but when I go to the actual page it is messed up.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

Here are some screenshots:

https://www.upload.ee/image/6217776/views.png https://www.upload.ee/image/6217778/screwed_up_thumbnails.png

Comment: Screenshots of the settings:
[Views settings](https://www.upload.ee/image/6217780/views_settings.png),
[Image settings](https://www.upload.ee/image/6217781/thumbnail_settings.png)

Answer (score 0):

you might have some CSS issue or override on your theme that makes the img look funny. 
If you are printing fields from the view you can specify a class to wrap your image into and than target that with specific css

Answer (score 0):

Apply CSS properties like margin and padding to img field. You can apply CSS to img filed either in any css file like (/public/sites/all/themes/css/screen.css) or in view itself you can apply css by giving CSS class name to fields.